# Adding images in layered architecture in tkinter canvas

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

I am creating a GUI application using tkinter Python (containing Treeview and Canvas) and I want to add/overlay multiple images in the same canvas area of my GUI window. Like for eg. if I want to insert suppose say 3 images in my application, the treeview should get updated with the names of the 3 images and if I click on one of the Image name in the treeview that particular Image should appear on the canvas while other images should be behind the current clicked image. Also if I delete any of the treeview entry, the corresponding image should only be removed from the canvas and other images should be present in the canvas.

```
def canvas_pic(img):
    image = img
    canvas_pic.counter += 1
    tree.insert("", canvas_pic.counter, "dir"+str(canvas_pic.counter), 
         text="Image"+str(canvas_pic.counter))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.imshow(image)
    canvas1.draw()

fig = Figure(figsize=(15, 2), dpi=100)
canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1, padx=10, pady=5)
```

I expect output to be like when I click a particular image name present in the treeview that particular image should be displayed on the canvas whereas other images should not get deleted or destroyed. Also if I delete any of the treeview entry then the particular image should only be deleted/removed from the canvas.